# OS portable memcpy optimized for SSE2 & SSE3

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, memcpy, icc

If I was to write a OS portable `memcpy` optimized for SSE2/SSE3 how would that look like? I want to support both the GCC and ICC compilers. The reason I ask is that `memcpy` is written in assembler code in glibc and not optimized for SSE2/SSE3, and other generic `memcpy` implementations may not fully take advantage of the systems capabilities with data alignment and size etc.

Here is my current `memcpy` that take data alignment into consideration and is optimized for SSE2 (I think) but not for SSE3:

```
#ifdef __SSE2__
// SSE2 optimized memcpy()
void *CMemUtils::MemCpy(void *restrict b, const void *restrict a, size_t n)
{
    char *s1 = b;
    const char *s2 = a;
    for(; 0<n; --n)*s1++ = *s2++;
    return b;
}
#else
// Generic memcpy() implementation
void *CMemUtils::MemCpy(void *dest, const void *source, size_t count) const
{
#ifdef _USE_SYSTEM_MEMCPY
    // Use system memcpy()
    return memcpy(dest, source, count);
#else

    size_t blockIdx;
    size_t blocks = count >> 3;
    size_t bytesLeft = count - (blocks << 3);

    // Copy 64-bit blocks first
    _UINT64 *sourcePtr8 = (_UINT64*)source;
    _UINT64 *destPtr8 = (_UINT64*)dest;
    for (blockIdx = 0; blockIdx < blocks; blockIdx++) destPtr8[blockIdx] = sourcePtr8[blockIdx];

    if (!bytesLeft) return dest;

    blocks = bytesLeft >> 2;
    bytesLeft = bytesLeft - (blocks << 2);

    // Copy 32-bit blocks
    _UINT32 *sourcePtr4 = (_UINT32*)&sourcePtr8[blockIdx];
    _UINT32 *destPtr4 = (_UINT32*)&destPtr8[blockIdx];
    for (blockIdx = 0; blockIdx < blocks; blockIdx++) destPtr4[blockIdx] = sourcePtr4[blockIdx];

    if (!bytesLeft) return dest;

    blocks = bytesLeft >> 1;
    bytesLeft = bytesLeft - (blocks << 1);

    // Copy 16-bit blocks
    _UINT16 *sourcePtr2 = (_UINT16*)&sourcePtr4[blockIdx];
    _UINT16 *destPtr2 = (_UINT16*)&destPtr4[blockIdx];
    for (blockIdx = 0; blockIdx < blocks; blockIdx++) destPtr2[blockIdx] = sourcePtr2[blockIdx];

    if (!bytesLeft) return dest;

    // Copy byte blocks
    _UINT8 *sourcePtr1 = (_UINT8*)&sourcePtr2[blockIdx];
    _UINT8 *destPtr1 = (_UINT8*)&destPtr2[blockIdx];
    for (blockIdx = 0; blockIdx < bytesLeft; blockIdx++) destPtr1[blockIdx] = sourcePtr1[blockIdx];
    return dest;
#endif
}
#endif
```

Not all `memcpy` implementations are thread-safe, which is just another reason to make our own version. All this leads me to conclude I should at least try to make a thread-safe OS portable `memcpy` that is optimized for SSE2/SSE3 where available.

I've also read that GCC supports *aggressive unrolling* with the `-funroll-loops` compiler option, could this improve performance with SSE2 and/or SSE3 if there are no significant cache misses?

Is there a performance gain of making different memcpy versions for 32-and 64-bit architectures?

Is there any performance gain of pre-aligning internal memory buffers before copying?

How do I use the `#pragma loop` to controls how loop code is to be considered by the SSE2/SSE3 auto-parallelizer? Supposedly one could use `#pragma loop` on contiguous data regions are moved by a for() loop.

Do I need to use the GCC compiler option `-fno-builtin-memcpy` even with `-O3` to force the compiler from inlining the GCC `memcpy` when adding my own `memcpy`? Or perhaps just overriding `memcpy` in my code is enough?

Update:
After some tests it seems to me that an SSE2 optimized `memcpy()` is not that much faster for it to be worth the effort. I've asked a [question in that regard on the Intel C/C++ Compiler forums](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/475426).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood - why do you think current memcpy implementations are not SSE* (or AVX*) optimized? see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425022/performance-of-x86-rep-instructions-on-modern-pipelined-superscalar-processors

Comment: @Leeor Mostly because this Intel paper says so http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/memcpy-performance , at least thats how I read it. glibc memcpy is written in asm and not optimized for SSE*, and GCC memcpy have serious perfomance issues it says.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen "glibc is written in ASM"? Where did you get that from? Or are you talking about `memcpy` only?

Comment: @us2012 Yes, glibc `memcpy` is written in asm - not the entire glibc library.

Comment: @IngeHenriksen, thanks for the link, i'd like to look further into that. Keep in mind that rep-strings should be able to perform most of the above code internally using the max HW bandwidth (and including the painful alignment checks), as described in the optimization guides.